# Python Script To Upload 300,000 files- Sqlite3 or massive list?

Tags: python, file-upload, sqlite, multiprocessing

I am writing a script that will upload files to a cloud account. There will be various directories containing the files, but only one depth...there will be **no** nested/directories inside of directories. Each directory will be a container in which the files will go in. Sometimes the files may be as large as 300,000 files. I will be using multiprocessing.

I would like to keep track of the filenames, outoutput information, returns codes using sqlite, so I had a few questions:

1) If I only had sqlite3 run in memory rather than as flat files(since I only need the info untill I'm done with the script) would it bloat the memory?
2) Would there be a major performance impact using sqlite3 as opposed to keeping track with a massive list of lists or a dictionary of lists?

Comment: no...there will be multiple folders from root....but the total amount of files is around 300,000

Comment: and the only way to answer your questions is to try it, but if you use a disk-based sqlite a lot of your synchronization headaches go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep the results on disk, you can use a dictionary structure in your main process.
Then you can use `.imap_unordered` to manage the results in realtime.

In pseudocode

```
files = [....] 
results = {}

r = pool.imap_unordered(uploadfile, files)
for res in r:
  results[res.fileid] = res.statuscode #for example

print_results_summary()
```

The memory impact depends on the info you store in the `results` dictionary.
For 300.000 entries storing a result status code it isn't too much.

On my system, a dictionary with 300.000 `int` values made the python process grow by around 20mb.